# Sending a Ajax signal from a PhoneGap App does not work

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I am trying to develop a Mobile App using the PhoneGap technology.

By using a ajax call, I would like to send/receive data to/from a server.

I have read many articles about how to develop a mobile app and it does not work for me.

I have developed the app and it runs perfect as a web app.

When I try to convert it into a mobile app using the Adobe PhoneGap Build, and after I install it on my android phone, the mobile app does not trigger the ajax api call.

Please help, this is my fiorst mobile app, and I feel that I am missing something, maybe some specific rights, configs ...

This is my html/js/jquery/ajax code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>

        <title>Mobile App</title>

        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Mobile App V 1.0.0</h1>

        <p>Description for the mobile app.</p>

        <div data-role="page" id="home">

            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">

                <h1>Mobile App</h1>

            </div>

            <div data-role="main">

                <div id="api_result"></div>

            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" style="text-align:center;"  data-theme="b">
                <p>&copy; Mobile App</p>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="res/js/main.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

and the js/jquery/ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(
        function () {

            $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://192.168.1.101/phone-gap/apis/apps/digital-menu/digital-menu-api-v-1.0.1/",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $.mobile.loading('show')
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            $.mobile.loading('hide')
                        },
                        data: {},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (response) {
                            //console.error(JSON.stringify(response));
                            //alert('Works!');
                            $("#api_result").html('abc');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            //console.error("error");
                            //alert('Now working!');
                            $("#api_result").html('def');
                        }
                    }
            );

        }
);
```

Comment: Set your IP url to `localhost` and run it again

Comment: as a web app it works, as a mobile app it doesn't

Comment: Then upload it to real web server

Comment: in phonegap app you should run your code after deviceready event. also, do you have the plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist and configured access origin in config.xml?  and if your phone is in android 4.4 or > you should also configure Content-Security-Policy in your html.